# Object to List C# and SSIS

Tags: c#, list, generics, ssis

> Background:

Bit of a strange one. Using SSIS to deal with data coming from an API, my first script gets the data and puts it against a strongly typed model called **"TestModel"**

The SSIS package then saves the resulting information to a variable which is then passed into the next part of the SSIS package. Being SSIS name spaces are not carried around so each script task is in isolation.

**Script Task One Namespace: ST_a048e0de86e1432d8da6f60b5d7055db**

**Script Task Two Namespace: SC_0573a66ec6c0486a98ee00cea4365654**

> The Issue:

The second SSIS script task picks up the variable and reads it fine, I can in debug see all my rows and all the relevant data. Now things start getting weird, the type of the List when it reaches my second script

```
object {System.Collections.Generic.List<ST_a048e0de86e1432d8da6f60b5d7055db.TestModel>}
```

Each of the objects in this `Generic.List` has the Type of:

```
ST_a048e0de86e1432d8da6f60b5d7055db.TestModel
```

What can I do with this list? Pretty much nothing...
I have duplicated the **TestModel.cs** from script namespace one into namespace two hoping that it would just match on nicely if I created a new list and passed the object too it, alas no.

> What I have tried so far:

```
IEnumerable e = data as List<TestModel>; //Returns 0 rows
IEnumerable list = (IEnumerable)data; // returns all rows, type System.Collections.IEnumerable {System.Collections.Generic.List<ST_a048e0de86e1432d8da6f60b5d7055db.TestModel>}
List<TestModel> listtest = ((TestModel[])data).ToList()  // Runtime error
List<TestModel> listtest2 = list.Cast<TestModel>().ToList(); //Runtime error - Unable to cast type 'ST_a048e0de86e1432d8da6f60b5d7055db.TestModel' to type 'SC_0573a66ec6c0486a98ee00cea4365654.TestModel'
```

My end goal is that I need something I can loop through and manipulate into an object SSIS can digest. That part is easy but getting it to loop is proving very difficult!

Extra Note: SSIS Packages are really annoying with dependencies so really looking to avoid using anything special. Also the name spaces are 100% isolated from on another no communication between the two is possible.

Comment: SSIS is an ETL tool, what are you trying to do with SSIS that cannot be done with a C# application? Or, why are you not handling everything with one script task? SSIS's strengths are in the data flow tab with the pipeline engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Enumerable.OfType Method (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 List<TestModel> list = ((IEnumerable)data).OfType<TestModel>().ToList();
```

UPDATE:

```
IEnumerable list = (IEnumerable)data;

foreach(var testModel in list)
{
    // manipulate testModel into an object SSIS can digest
}
```

Comment: That kinda works, the list creates without a runtime error though it contains 0 rows, similar to the command List<TestModel> Test1 = data as List<TestModel>. Thanks for trying though

Comment: @Caz1224 can't you just loop through your IEnumerable to do your thing? IEnumerable list = (IEnumerable)data; works for you right. You can foreach on it.

Comment: The foreach does work in a sense that I can loop through the list, though what is passed into the loop is an object with the old type on it, this gives me no ability to say iteminloop.Index or iteminloop[Index] as it has nothing in it but to string on the entire object.

Comment: Have you tied IEnumerable<ST_a048e0de86e1432d8da6f60b5d7055db.TestModel> list = (IEnumerable<ST_a048e0de86e1432d8da6f60b5d7055db.TestModel>)data; ???

Comment: Yeah I have tried that, it gets upset because in the second script it has no knowledge of the ST_a048e0de86e1432d8da6f60b5d7055db namespace

Comment: If you want to cheat your way then you could convert the object to a JSON string in the 1st script so when you pass it to the 2nd script you can deserialize it to a list of <T> and loop your way to an object that SSIS can digest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109862/discussion-between-caz1224-and-ephraim).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map your TestModel classes to each other. It's easy to setup and use.

This is off the top of my head so it might need tweaking, but the code would look very similar to this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    CreateMap<ST_a048e0de86e1432d8da6f60b5d7055db.TestModel
              , SC_0573a66ec6c0486a98ee00cea4365654.TestModel>();
    cfg.AddProfile<testModel>();
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

Then you could convert the `listTest` using the `mapper` like this:

```
var convertedList = mapper.Map<ST_a048e0de86e1432d8da6f60b5d7055db.TestModel>
                  , IList<SC_0573a66ec6c0486a98ee00cea4365654.TestModel>>(listTest);
```

EDIT: Attempt 2

You said you tried moving the `TestModel` class to the second namespace.  If not you may need to add it in or something equivalent. Then it might be as simple as trying this:

```
var listTest = data.Select(x => new TestModel 
                       { property1 = x.property1,
                         property2 = x.property2
                         //etc...
                         }).ToList();
```

That should give you a new `List<TestModel>`

Comment: I might keep your answer as a last resort, loading dependencies are really painful in SSIS and I would like to avoid them if I can

Comment: Just had a look at this again... And it probably wont work. In the second script ST_a048e0de86e1432d8da6f60b5d7055db.TestModel doesn't exist. Each script functions as an independent project

Comment: Good in theory, though data is still an object and doesn't have .select as a function

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to expand on John Ephraim Tugado's solution since it seemed a little incomplete

```
public void Main()
{
    try
    {
        List<TestModel> testModelList = BuildObjectList();

        TestModel testModel = new TestModel();

        testModel.prop1 = "new prop";
        testModel.prop2 = true;

        testModelList.Add(testModel);

        //Now that we have a testModelList in the correct local class we can 
        //modify it and load it back into the globally held variable for 
        //another Component to use

        Dts.Variables["User::myObjectList"].Value = testModelList;

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    catch
    {
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
}

private List<TestModel> BuildObjectList()
{
    try
    {
        List<TestModel> RunningList = new List<TestModel>();
        TestModel localModel = new TestModel();

        var data = Dts.Variables["User::myObjectList"].Value;
        IEnumerable enumDataList = (IEnumerable)data;

        foreach (var currentObj in enumDataList)
        {
            localModel = GetSingleResult(currentObj);
            RunningList.Add(localModel);
            localModel = new TestModel();
        }
        return RunningList;
    }
    catch
    {
        return new List<TestModel>();
    }
}

private TestModel GetSingleResult(object currentObj)
{
    try
    {
        TestModel returnedResult = new TestModel();

        PropertyInfo[] properties = currentObj.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
        {
            switch (pi.Name)
            {
                case "prop1":
                    returnedResult.prop1 = pi.GetValue(currentObj, null).ToString();
                    break;
                case "prop2":
                    returnedResult.prop2 = Convert.ToBoolean(pi.GetValue(currentObj, null));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        return returnedResult;
    }
    catch {
        return new TestModel();
    }
}

internal class TestModel
{
    internal string prop1 { get; set; }
    internal bool prop2 { get; set; }
}
```